# FontAwesome.Sharp Spinner not stopping

Tags: c#, wpf

I am converting a .NET Framework C# application to a .NET Core C# application.  I had to change from using FontAwesome.WPF to FontAwesome.Sharp. I have the code in the MainWindow.xaml as follows:

```
xmlns:fa="http://schemas.awesome.incremented/wpf/xaml/fontawesome.sharp"
<fa:IconBlock x:Name="initDBProgressIcon" Icon="Spinner" fa:Awesome.Spin="True" fa:Height="20" fa:Width="20"/>
```

The above code will cause the spinner to spin but I need to change the icon and stop the spinning. I am using the following code to change to a different icon but I can't sop the spinning because Spin is not a method as it was in FontAwesome.WPF.  I need to know how to stop the spinner from spinning.

```
           initDBProgressIcon.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));
           //initDBProgressIcon.Spin = false;
           initDBProgressIcon.Icon = FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.Check;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the attached `Spin` property to `false` like this:

```
FontAwesome.Sharp.Awesome.SetSpin(initDBProgressIcon, false);
```